# How to wait for response in method.then() in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

`method.then()` inside AppComponent never gets called in below scenario-

This is my load method in service-

```
load(): Promise<IAppSettings> {
        return this.http.get('api/AppSettingsApi')
            .toPromise()
            .then((response: Response) => {
                this._appSettings = response;
                console.log('this._appSettings: ' + JSON.stringify(this._appSettings));
                return this._appSettings;
            })
            .catch((error) => Promise.reject(error.message || error));
```

From above block, I can see correct output in 
`console.log('this._appSettings: ' + JSON.stringify(this._appSettings));`

This how I am calling load method of service from AppComponent constructor-

```
constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private customerService: CustomerService,
        private appSettings: AppSettingsService,
        ) {

this.appSettings.load()
            .then((data) => {
                console.log('config loaded successfully');
                console.log('========================================================================');
                this.envName = data.environmentSettings.envName;
                console.log('this.envName: ' + this.envName);
                console.log('========================================================================');

            })
            .catch(() => { console.error('Error occurred while loading config'); });
```

But my on `then()` part never gets called. I don't see any error in browser console.

I want to wait for response in my AppComponent method, Could you please guide me on this?

Comment: Try to add `.first()` before `.toPromise()` like `return this.http.get(...).first().toPromise().then(...)`. (`first` needs to be imported like `toPromise`.

Comment: Have you tried using Observable instead of Promise? Using Observable should be more consistent even if you just subscribre, you don't have to convert it to a promise and it saves you some calls.

Comment: Thanks Gunter - first() worked.

Comment: Supamiu - will give a try with Observable too.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of `Service` :

```
serviceFunction() {
    let jwt = "jwt here";
    let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            "Authorization" : jwt
        });
      let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.http.get(this.APIUrl, options).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

and here, I call my service from my `Component` :

```
this.serviceName.serviceFunction()
            .subscribe(
                res => {   
                    // in case of success
                },
                err => {
                    // in case of errors
                }
            );
```

Hope that helps u :)